Why is flyway trying to connect to localhost when I have specified the URL to connect to
Running flyway locally works perfectly but when I try to run it as a task in ECS I get the following error message:
Unable to obtain connection from database
(jdbc:postgresql:<myrdsdb>.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/<mydb>?ssl=true&sslmode=require) 
for user 'flyway_user': Connection to localhost:5432 refused. 

Check that the hostname and port are correct 
and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

I ensured that everything was set up correctly on ECS, the security groups allowed access and that I was able to connect to the DB on the EC2 instance that the task was running on.
Posting this question because I spent two days looking into this and I have the solution

I found the solution, eventually after 3 days of investigation I saw that the jdbc url was misconfigured, it was missing the // part of the path.
It seems like javax.sql.datasource will fall back to localhost if it can't parse the jdbc URL
